# Merge by distance acting strange in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

As you can see on this gif, I have 1.3k vertices on perfect lines from -Y to +Y. I want to merge them to get start and end points. But unfortunately, merge by distance doesn't work properly? It only starts from 300um and ignores lower numbers. How i can fix it? is there another way to get start-end points from lines like this?
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Well, that probably means distance between vertices are simply bigger than 200+ums? Anyways, instead of `Curve to Mesh` and `Merge`, I'd use a `Delete Geometry` with `Endpoint Selection`: 1 and 1 > `Not` feeding the *Selection* socket. Meaning, delete all points of the curve except the first and last. Deleting curve points is more like dissolving them, it wouldn't leave gaps behind like with mesh.

Comment: @Kuboå Well, distance between the points is 0 µm) But up to 300 it does not work, as shown in the gif
Unfortunately, I can't use your method just because all these lines are not one curve with many points. Its many of them, so first of all i need to merge them into one

Comment: Why aren't you just instantiating the curves with just two points?

Comment: @Sforz That's vital information you've left out of your question! Can you share your file (at least that curves part) on blend-exchange.com so we can take a look?